# How do I exclude a subfolder of a subfolder in compress-archive

Tags: powershell, compress-archive

I want to zip a folder containing files, and subfolders containing more files and more subfolders. But I want exclude just one subfolder of a subfolder. I have seen many various complicated answers but none seem to really work on this scenario.

folder structure

```
temp/
   a/
     aa/
        aaa/
            aaaa/
                 filesinaaaa.txt
            filesinaaa.txt
        filesinaa.txt
     at.txt
   b/
     bb/
     bt.txt
   c.txt
```

I want to exclude all files in a/aa/aaa/ while keeping the resulting zip in the same dir structure. And if possible remove the files that were included in the zip.

So result expected is

```
temp/
  a/
     aa/
        aaa/
            aaaa/
                 filesinaaaa.txt
            filesinaaa.txt
  result.zip
```

In linux it is as simple as

```
cd temp
zip -rm result.zip . -x "a/aa/aaa/*"
```

what is the simplest way to do this in powershell?

answers i've tried do not really work on subfolder of a subfolder.

[Exclude sub-directories from Compress-Archive Powershell Cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299445/exclude-sub-directories-from-compress-archive-powershell-cmd?rq=1)

[How do I exclude a folder in compress-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081488/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-in-compress-archive)

over complicated result
[Archive folder without some subfolders and files using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171826/archive-folder-without-some-subfolders-and-files-using-powershell?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You want to exclude the folder too or only the files inside that folder? Do you want to exclude the subfolders of that subfolder too (if it has any) ?

Comment: yes, i want to exclude everything inside aaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 7z CLI to do so, [here](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/exclude.htm) is the doc explaining the usage of `-x` option in 7z

#### Showing an example of the option below for reference

The directory structure explained in the question:

```
C:\Users\adam_\Desktop\temp〉dir -R
a  b  c.txt

./a:
aa  at.txt

./a/aa:
aaa  filesinaa.txt

./a/aa/aaa:
aaaa  filesinaaa.txt

./a/aa/aaa/aaaa:
filesinaaaa.txt

./b:
bb  bt.txt

./b/bb:
```

Creating the archive:

```
PS C:\Users\adam_\Desktop\temp> 7z a -tzip result.zip . -x!a/aa/aaa/*

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive:
5 folders, 4 files, 63 bytes (1 KiB)

Creating archive: result.zip

Add new data to archive: 5 folders, 4 files, 63 bytes (1 KiB)


Files read from disk: 4
Archive size: 1217 bytes (2 KiB)
Everything is Ok
```

Result archive details:

```
PS C:\Users\adam_\Desktop\temp> 7z l .\result.zip

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1217 bytes (2 KiB)

Listing archive: .\result.zip

--
Path = .\result.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 1217

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-05-05 09:48:37 D....            0            0  a
2022-05-05 09:48:12 D....            0            0  a\aa
2022-05-05 09:47:45 D....            0            0  a\aa\aaa
2022-05-05 09:48:12 ....A           13           13  a\aa\filesinaa.txt
2022-05-05 09:48:37 ....A           13           13  a\at.txt
2022-05-05 09:49:20 D....            0            0  b
2022-05-05 09:48:58 D....            0            0  b\bb
2022-05-05 09:49:20 ....A           19           19  b\bt.txt
2022-05-05 09:49:56 ....A           18           18  c.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-05-05 09:49:56                 63           63  4 files, 5 folders
```