# Powershell Compress-Archive not publishing Node.js AWS lambda layer correctly

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, aws-lambda, azure-devops

I work at a company that deploys Node.js and C# AWS lambda functions. I work on a windows machine. Our azure pipeline build environment is also windows environment.

I wrote a powershell script that packages lambda functions and layers as zip files and publishes them to AWS. My issue is deploying node.js lambda layers.

When I use Compress-Archive powershell command to zip the layer files it is preserving the windows `\` in file paths. When this gets unzipped in AWS it is expecting `/` in file paths. So the file structure is incorrect for a node.js runtime and my lambda function that uses layer cannot find needed modules.

One way I made this work from my local machine is to install 7zip utility to zip the files. It seems it zips the files with `/` file paths and this works correctly when unzipped for lambda layer using node.js runtime. But when I use this powershell script in azure pipeline I cannot install 7zip utility on the build server.

Is there a way to zip files with `/` in file paths instead of `\` that does not require to use a third party utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Compress-Archive` doesn't keep folder structure and more details and workarounds you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392050/compress-archive-and-preserve-relative-paths). But apart from that you can use `Archive Files task` (link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops)), or install 7zip using chocolatey `choco install 7zip.install -y`.

Comment: Using the pipeline Archive Files task will keep the / in the directory path. Thank you for the help!